# Maximized IE window in VBS

Tags: vbscript

[image: ERROR]Need help to maximize the IE window in VB script. Tried several options but in vain.

```
Option Explicit


Dim objApp, nIE, oIE, Window

Set objApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set oIE = Nothing


For Each Window In objApp.Windows
If InStr(Window.Name, "Internet Explorer") Then
Set oIE = Window
End If
Next

If oIE Is Nothing Then
Call NewIE
Else
Call OpenIE
End If


'Internet Explorer is closed.
Sub NewIE()
Set nIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
nIE.Navigate2 "https://www.bbc.com"
nIE.Navigate2 "https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft- 
365/onedrive/online-cloud-storage", 4096
nIE.Visible = True

End Sub

'Internet Explorer is already opened.
 Sub OpenIE()
 oIE.Navigate2 "https://www.bbc.com", 2048
 oIE.Navigate2 "https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft- 
 365/onedrive/online-cloud-storage", 4096
 oIE.Visible = True

 End Sub
```

Comment: https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1364653

Comment: Get error after adding the script

Answer (score 0):

For information about the IE object, [IE Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752084(v=vs.85))

The problem is that whether or not IE starts full screen is determined by either a registry setting or by group policy, both of which vbscript may not have access to since these require elevated permissions.  Ref [Maximizing IE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/browsers/core-features/how-to-set-fullscreen)

The tek-tips method will work if the Maximize button is visible.

Comment: It seems there are some vba code in excel can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `nIE.FullScreen = True` and `oIE.FullScreen = True` to your script:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objApp, nIE, oIE, Window
Set objApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set oIE = Nothing

For Each Window In objApp.Windows
  If InStr(Window.Name, "Internet Explorer") Then
    Set oIE = Window
  End If
Next

If oIE Is Nothing Then
  Call NewIE
Else
  Call OpenIE
End If

'Internet Explorer is closed.
Sub NewIE()
Set nIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
nIE.Navigate2 "https://www.bbc.com"
nIE.Navigate2 "https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/onedrive/online-cloud-storage", 4096
nIE.Visible = True
nIE.FullScreen = True
End Sub

'Internet Explorer is already opened.
 Sub OpenIE()
 oIE.Navigate2 "https://www.bbc.com", 2048
 oIE.Navigate2 "https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/onedrive/online-cloud-storage", 4096
 oIE.Visible = True
 oIE.FullScreen = True
 End Sub
```

Please note that a lot of websites no longer work with IE and many that do work now may not work in the near future.

Comment: Hi, this open IE in full screen.

Comment: If this answered your question, please click the checkmark. Thank you.

Comment: It opens IE in full screen but crashed.

Comment: That's not a VBScript issue and not a fault in the provided code. You can't expect IE to work reliably with modern web sites. Use a modern browser, such as Chrome. You can control Chrome via a script, using [selenium basic](https://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/).

Comment: Can the IE application be changed to MS Edge instead !

Comment: You can change IE to Edge but it isn't a COM application.  You have to launch it using shell run.  Look for MS WebDriver if you wish to drive the HTML.